# Python : Can I specify start up geometry when launching process from python?

Tags: python, process

I'm new to python.

I'm launching processes from my application through "subProcess.Popen" method on Linux

I need to specify application geometry when it starts up. like start with 800*400 or start as full screen app.

It looked into the arguments of Popen method

```
class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None,       stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)
```

but I didn't find any option that could satisfy my requirement

Is it possible through any other way ? or the each app itself should have something like argument to specify the width and height during startup ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of `Popen`, and the window size is ultimately determined by your window manager.

However, you can use programs such as [wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/) to resize a window after the program has started.